# Disable Wagtail "copy" functionality

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to disable the copy functionality provided in Wagtail?

My team has some logic for a custom page type that is having some issues. We'd like to prevent people from using the copy functionality for a short period of time while we figure out what's going on, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `before_copy_page` hook, e.g. to redirect editors to the listings page with a notification explaining that copying has been temporarily disabled:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/reference/hooks.html#before-copy-page

Comment: That seems like a perfect approach, and low impact too. Thanks Tom!

Comment: @tomd, is there a way to use that hook to customize the fields displayed on the copy dialog that allows users to change the slug associated with the page? Preferably, without having to make a whole new copy interface from scratch?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640685/how-do-i-customize-the-wagtail-page-copy-experience